# MBWC using two twin breakers with middle handles tied

Tags: mwbc

My question is whether overload protection will work for the two handle tied circuits described below:

Four separate circuits are involved.  These are in a residence, feeding outlets and lights, including some GFCI's. 
Two twin 15 amp breakers, with the red and black of a 14/3 wire to the middle two, and the black of two 14/2 wires to the "outside" two.

1 - circuit 1, black wire from a 14/2 
2 - circuit 2, black wire from the 14/3 
3 - circuit 3, red wire from the same 14/3
4 - circuit 4, black wire from a different 14/2

Circuits 2 and 3 are handle tied with a screw through the holes in the switches.

Circuits 1 and 4 are normal, so these should be ok.
Circuits 2 and 3 are on separate busses, so there is 240V between them, which means the neutral should not become overloaded.  This is ok.
When shutting off 2 and 3 for maintenance, both circuits will be shut off together, avoiding a surprise hot neutral.  This is ok.

My question is whether the overload protection will work correctly in this configuration?

If it will work correctly, I understand that both circuits 2 and 3 will shut off together, which is fine.

I reviewed several similar questions but didn't see this exact situation described.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Chuck

Comment: What make and model are your circuit breakers?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Eaton BD1515.  They are both the same.

Answer (score 1):

### This is *almost* right

While circuit 2 tripping won't cause the breaker for 3 to trip (nor will it happen the other way around), it won't need to -- since there are only 120V loads present, a fault on circuit 2 will be de-energized by the breaker for circuit 2 tripping, and likewise for circuit 3.  (You'd need a *common trip* breaker to have both circuits de-energized at once should the breaker trip.)

### But, you need a proper *handle tie* for this

However, a screw does not a handle tie make.  All current production breaker lines have a proper handle tie available for them, although you will likely need to go to an electrical supply house to obtain one, or order the correct one for your breakers online provided you know what make and model breakers you have.

In your case, by the way, your Eaton BD1515s need an Eaton THS1 handle tie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I only saw the comment at first.  I will seek out a proper handle tie, and see if I can get it in place.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like my local Platt Electric has them.  I'll pick one up tomorrow.

Comment: FYI Platt usually only sells to licensed folks, or that used to be there policy, you may want to check before going to town.